Problem connecting to smtp.outlook.com using OAuth and MASL4J
in my Java application I have been able to send an email using just my outlook.com address to connect to smtp.office365.com. Recently this stopped working because Microsoft have disabled basic authentication, and supports only OAuth. So I have tried to update my code to use the msal4j library, and have made some progress, but am not yet at the point when I can send a message using OAuth. Here's what I have done:

Logged in to entra.micorosft.com and registered an app. I have generated a client secret for the app.
In the registered app, I have granted it the SMTP.Send permission.
I have updated my Java application as follows:

            /* Set up connection to generate access token */
            String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + myTenantId;
            String applicationIDURI = myApplicationIDURI (from the Entra UI);
            Set<String> scope = new HashSet();
            scope.add(applicationIDURI + "/.default");
            IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);
            ConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientID, credential)
                    .authority(authority)
                    .build();
            ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scope)
                    .build();
            IAuthenticationResult result = confidentialClientApplication.acquireToken(parameters)
                    .join();
            String oauthToken = result.accessToken();
            /* Can print out this token - it looks reasonable */
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.disable", "false");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
//          properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", encodedOauthToken);
//          System.out.println("using encoded oauthToken");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
            System.out.println("using unencoded oauthToken");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, 
                new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, oauthToken);    
                    }
                }
            );
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            /* Set content and recipients in message */
            Transport.send(message);

When this code runs, I can see an access token being generated as expected, and a connection being made to the SMTP server. However, when Transport.send(message) is called an exception is thrown (see below). I assume that I have misconfigured either the registered application, or the code above is misconfiguring the client, but I cannot see what the problem is, and have tried many different combinations of things!
Thanks for any help! Martin
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO host.docker.internal
250-BY3PR05CA0058.outlook.office365.com Hello [99.47.70.212]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.office365.com, user=myUsername@outlook.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Authenticate with SASL
DEBUG SMTP: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG SMTP:  LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: 
DEBUG SMTP: SASL client XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback length: 2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@53fdffa1
DEBUG SMTP: SASL callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@5562c41e
AUTH XOAUTH2 <long string snipped>
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BY3PR05CA0058.namprd05.prod.outlook.com 2024-10-13T16:17:32.016Z 08DCEB390DE37C0D]
DEBUG SMTP: SASL authentication failed
jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:379)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at jakarta.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at jakarta.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)

